# Pick Product Option Value Based On Line-Item-Property

Tags: html, css, json, shopify, liquid

Using ThemeDawn v9

Created two line-item-properties on a product page as text form fields
The product has multiple options

Regarding one of these options (let's call it option z),

i want customers to input numbers inside the text form fields.

Based one these customer inputs, the specific option value should be selected

If the sum of these two form fields is between 1-20, option value x of option z is selected
If the sum of these two form fields is between 21-40, option value y of option z is selected
Furthermore:

Hide the normal option value selection of option z, so that you can only change the option value of option z by inserting numbers inside these two text form fields
Don't hide other option value selections for that product
Limit text form fields to integral number, no text allowed
Limit text form fields to a specific number range

1. Possible? How?
2. Possible to add sliders to the customer inputs? So that the value in the text form field changes according to the slider and vice versa? How?

Thank you very much!